# Double Summation in Python

Tags: python, math, numpy, equations

I am trying to write a code to conduct a double summation (see pic)

[image]

in which; 
M is the subjects,
N is the Trials,
Yijt is the measured wave form data (3d array)

so far I have; 
Given Y is the data arranged as Y[subjects, trials, time]

```
# ranges:
I = len(Y)
J = len(Y[0])

Y_i_vals = 0

for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        Y_i_vals = Y_i_vals +Y[i][j]
Yt = (1.0/(M*N)) * Y_i_vals
```

this doesnt seem the most effective way to do this, nor am i certain it is giving the correct result.

Comment: Do you know [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)? That would be much faster. Or in that case, try to use [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Did you mean `Y[i][j]`, not `Y[M][N]`?

Comment: @Michael0x2a Thanks, have now corrected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `numpy` just do

```
np.mean(Y)
```

Also, it's good to add sample input and expected output data to your question.

If you want means for each `t` you can do `np.mean(np.mean(a, axis=0), axis=0)`
, or as noted by @ophion you can shorten this to `np.mean(a, axis=(0, 1))` in newer (1.71 and on) versions of NumPy.

Comment: This would compute the mean over all 3 dimensions, where the desire is to generate separate means over *M* and *N* for each *t*. (Unless *Y* in the code really represents a slice for a specific *t*.)

Comment: Updated. Adding expected input and output would make it much clearer!

Comment: In numpy 1.7.1 you can simplify this to `np.mean(a, axis=(0,1))`

Comment: @Ophion nice, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

To add a more general answer to your question:

You can code a double summation with the help of python list comprehension.

```
Yt = (1.0/(M*N)) * sum([Y[i][j] for i in range(M) for j in range(N)])
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to simple double summations like in your case, it's nice to use numpy's einsum:

```
np.einsum('tij -> t', Y) / (M*N)
```