# How to write double summation in Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and want to write the following equation in Python.

[image]

Comment: [Double Summation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274813/double-summation-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double Summation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274813/double-summation-in-python)

Comment: yes. i see this post. however, my equation has 3 matrcies x, t, and x. Also it multiply x, t and i. could one give an example.

Comment: elcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

basically, it's just a double for loop (nested loop), a for loop within a for loop

```
def tau(i, J, K):
  total = 0
  for j in J:
    for k in K:
      total += y(i, j)*t(j,k)*x(i,k)
  return total
```

of course, you can collapse this to a few lines by using `reduce` and `list comprehension`. You might want to look those up if this is the first time you're hearing about them

BTW, I'm assuming you want vanilla python. If you're dealing with matrices, please look at the `numpy` library